# unhandled level 3 permission fault (11) [ error disappears when running gdb...! ]

Tags: gcc, gdb, arm, valgrind, arm64

So I am trying to run my c++ application on an aarch64(ARM 8). ***When run using GDB the application runs without any problem. But otherwise it gives me a segmentation fault.***I checked dmesg and it goes as

```
unhandled level 3 permission fault (11) at 0x004ac010, esr 0x8300000f

[241808.064733] pgd = ffffffc0fe270000

[241808.068270] [004ac010] *pgd=00000001615c9003, *pmd=000000016f316003, *pte=02e0000147f42f53

[241808.076813] 

[241808.076824] CPU: 2 PID: 12503 Comm: Jumpi Not tainted 3.10.67-g3a5c467 #1

[241808.076832] task: ffffffc0fef9c080 ti: ffffffc0f0fe4000 task.ti: ffffffc0f0fe4000

[241808.076841] PC is at 0x4ac010

[241808.076846] LR is at 0x401cb8

[241808.076852] pc : [<00000000004ac010>] lr : [<0000000000401cb8>] pstate: 20000000

[241808.076857] sp : 0000007fc044b600

[241808.076863] x29: 0000007fc044b680 x28: 0000000000000000

[241808.076873] x27: 0000000000000000 x26: 0000000000000000 

[241808.076882] x25: 00000000004186ec x24: 0000000000418634
```

I tried set disable-randomization off in gdb but still no error.I then tried valgrind. I get a lot of error messages saying unitialised value was created ,mostly at dl_init_paths.But more importantly I get the bad permission generating SISGEV at a memory address which when i went through memory seems to be in  (env_path_list) . 
That where i am at after debugging for hours.If anyone has any suggestions/ideas about the next steps that would be helpful.
Another interesting fact is when the same code was compiled using a cross compiler and ran on this (ARM8) it works fine...!!

Comment: From a guess based on those addresses, it looks like you're trying to execute your data section, which smacks of an uninitialised pointer. My psychic prediction is that somewhere you're calling a virtual method on a freed object.

Comment: Did you look at the core dump?

Answer (score 0):

You can find detalied reason of fault in 'esr' register which already printed in crash dump. You can use armv8 spec to decode value of 'esr' register.

Comment: @kfsone Actually yes, the reason has been already mentioned in crash dump - permission fault. BTW as a solution, author can use objdump tool from aarch64 cross-tools for reading elf file and try to found out the problem place. The good start point is using value of LR register (0x401cb8) for founding problem code.